# How should I wire a ceiling fan remote where one switch is used to control the fixture?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Ceiling has red, black, white, and ground wire.  Remote box has black and white wires on top (to ceiling) and black, white, and blue wires on the bottom (to fan). The fan has black, white, blue, and ground wire.  The blue wire is for the light.  The instructions that came with the fan tell you to connect all the same color wires, but never addresses the red wire. I called the company and they said to connect the red wire to the blue wires. This works except that in order for the fan to work, the light has to be on. The remote will control the fan speeds, but will not control the light as it should.

Comment: Are you OK with ditching the remote you have and getting a different remote?

Comment: The remote is designed to allow separate control of fan and light when there is only one switched hot from a wall switch which is what you would have if there was originally just a ceiling light. The ele switch cant use two separate hots from the house wiring and if that is what you have, then you can use only one and must cap one of them. How many wall switches do you have? In normal operation you don't even need a wall switch, but I have found a wall switch to be a benefit for working on the fan because you can turn off the power to just the fan/light combo and leave the breaker on.

Comment: If there was originally a ceiling light fixture and a single gang switch box, all that wound be needed would be a /2 cable (black and white). But your /3 cable (black, red, white, ground) suggests it might be that the builder or the electrician put in  /3 in case someone later wanted to put in a fan/light combo. It would be easy to expand the switch box to a 2-gang and put in another switch. Much harder to replace the cable.

Answer (score 1):

Hot wires are any color but white, gray or green.  Code isn't specific as to which.  Since there's only 1 switch and not 2, surely the red/black are a) always-hot, and b) switched-hot.   We don't know which is which - there's no standard.

Normally you shouldn't experiment, but in this case, it's alright.

Turn the breaker off. Hook up ground.  Hook up neutral.

Now, the blue wire on the fan is actually for the light.  Hook that to either red or black from the ceiling, and cap the other one off.  See what that does.  Then hook it to the other one and see what *that* does.  Results will be:

- Is the light always-on?  That wire is always-hot.
- Is the light controlled by the switch?  That wire is switched-hot, *and leave this connected because that is what you actually want*.

Now, on the fan control module, there's a blue wire you won't use. Cap that off.  Also cap off the control module's bottom white wire, since you can't use it.

After that it's downhill; the only thing is you'll be adding the box's top white wire to the neutrals.